# date.toLocaleDateString(locale,{timeZone:'Asia/Kolkata'}) not working in ie 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am trying to convert date and time with timezone and locale but, it is not working in IE11. It is working in chrome, firefox, and edge.

**Minimally complete verifiable example:**

```
function getLocalTime(date){
    var timeZone = "Asia/Kolkata";
    var utcDate =  new Date(Date.UTC(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate(), date.getHours(), date.getMinutes(), date.getSeconds()));
    var dateAndTime = utcDate.toLocaleDateString("en",{timeZone:timeZone})+" "+ utcDate.toLocaleTimeString("en",{timeZone:timeZone}).replace(/:\d+ /, ' ');;
    return dateAndTime;
}

console.log(getLocalTime(Date());
```

**Error in IE11:**

`SCRIPT5118: Option value 'ASIA/KOLKATA' for 'timeZone' is outside of valid range. Expected: ['UTC']`

**Note:** I don't want to use any third party js.

Comment: Is it only that timezone or any timezone? When you say "not working" what is it doing? What's in the console if you hit F12.

Comment: It is throwing error as **'Option val ue 'ASIA/KOLKATA' for 'timeZone' is outside of valid range. Expected: ['UTC']'** but I want the date and time with timezone like Asia/Kolkata(set by user)

Comment: What is the value of timezonestr?

Comment: timezonestr is Asia/Kolkata.

Comment: What is the value of locale? I'll see if I can reproduce locally.

Comment: (You may want to update your question and flatten those variables to create a minimally complete and verifiable example.)

Comment: @mkaatman the value of locale is **en** generally the user set this in application.

Comment: Sure. I just want to make sure I am duplicating your example 100%. I will try this in a couple of hours.

Comment: I suspect the answer is that IE11 simply doesn't support that timezone. I've tried to find a list of timezones that are supported but I couldn't find anything. I'll put a bounty on this to see if someone else can figure out if there is a solution.

Comment: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-402/1.0/ states "[[timeZone]] is either the String value "UTC" or undefined."

Comment: @mkaatman I am facing this issue currently !! In case you can able to resolve it ?

Comment: I resolved it by requiring users upgrade to edge. Unfortunately, that's not a possibility for all developers though!

Comment: Has anyone found a reliable javascript third party library that overrides this method for all IANA time zones in IE11?

Answer (score 7):

[timeZone documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) says that support for timezone strings is optional, except for "UTC":

> The only value implementations must recognize is "UTC"; the default is the runtime's default time zone. Implementations may also recognize the time zone names of the IANA time zone database, such as "Asia/Shanghai", "Asia/Kolkata", "America/New_York".

Relevant portions of the [ECMAScript spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-402/1.0/) confirm this (hat tip to @mkaatman):

> [[timeZone]] is either the String value "UTC" or undefined.
>
> A conforming implementation is permitted to accept additional values, and then have implementation-defined behaviour instead of throwing a RangeError, for [...t]he options property timeZone in the DateTimeFormat constructor, provided that the additional acceptable input values are case-insensitive matches of Zone or Link identifiers in the IANA time zone database and are canonicalized to Zone identifiers in the casing used in the database for the timeZone property of the object returned by DateTimeFormat.resolvedOptions, except that "Etc/GMT" shall be canonicalized to "UTC".

[Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/tolocaledatestring-method-date-javascript) states they started supporting localeDateString in IE11:

> Starting in Internet Explorer 11, toLocaleDateString uses Intl.DateTimeFormat internally to format the date, which adds support for the locales and options parameters.

...but based on your error message their support is for the minimal "'UTC' or undefined" version.  The timezone database is [here](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) for what it's worth, but it looks like you'll need to find a different way to handle this (probably involving `getTimezoneOffset()` rather than named timezones.)

Comment: How can I get DST info for getTimezoneOffset()?

Comment: getTimezoneOffset() adjusts for daylight saving time automatically, so you'll get the correct offset whether or not DST is in effect for that zone at that time.   (If you need to detect specifically whether DST is in effect, though, that's harder -- the moment.js library hacks around the problem by just comparing the offset in December and in June...)

Comment: I need to know the correct local time to display for a meeting that will take place in Nov30 (for example) and I a unix timestamp. getTimezoneOffset() seems to only be relevant for today, no?

Comment: It's not relevant for "today", it's relevant for the date it's called against. Convert that unix timestamp to a Date, then call getTimezoneOffset() on that Date. `new Date(2018,1).getTimezoneOffset()` will give you different results than `new Date(2018,6).getTimezoneOffset()`