# I am getting an Invalid timezone specified when using the "Eurpe/London" timezone

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get the time for London but I am getting the error `Uncaught RangeError: Invalid time zone specified: Eurpe/London`. I was able to get that of America/New_York.

```js
const str2 = new Date().toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: 'Eurpe/London' });
uk_time = str2.split(" ")[1];

console.log(uk_time)
```

Comment: Spelling mistake? `Eurpe/London` -> `Europe/London`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [date.toLocaleDateString(locale,{timeZone:'Asia/Kolkata'}) not working in ie 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44402560/date-tolocaledatestringlocale-timezoneasia-kolkata-not-working-in-ie-11)

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo in `Eurpe/London`. Try

```
new Date().toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: 'Europe/London' })
```